# MySQL fetching all data on a sigle row

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I have a problem with my PHP code to retrieve information from a SQL database, the data base looks like

[image: My data base]
My code looks like:

```
$query="SELECT nDeCand FROM `candidats`";
$res=mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res,MYSQL_NUM);
$num= count($row);
echo "Printed Array: </br>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($row);
echo "</pre>";
```

And it prints:

Array
(
    [0] => 24567
)

I need it to retrieve all the numbers in nDeCand, not only the first one. 
Can anybody explain why it isn't doing it?

Comment: you need a while loop maybe ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only fetching the first row and accessing the value. You need to loop through all the rows. The mysql_fetch_assoc()  increments the pointer to the next row each time it is invoked in the while loop. This way you are able to access all the rows. This is the code:-

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $row['nDeCand'];
}
```

Comment: poor, very poor. try better another time. answering another question still is good and I see a lot of potential. The problem is to think that your explanation needs source-code to explain. It does not. Instead the source-code shows you do not trust your explanation for this really trivial question. I DV'ed this Q then and UV'ed other answer I thought are more worthy instead.

Answer (score 3):

You have to loop throug the rows using a while.

```
$query="SELECT nDeCand FROM `candidats`";
$res=mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($res,MYSQL_NUM)) {
  $num= count($row);
  echo "Printed Array: </br>";
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($row);
  echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first, you should be using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), not the `mysql_` functions, which are deprecated.

Beyond that, when using mysql_fetch_row (or mysqli_fetch_row, in the functional context), you'll need to call it in a loop:

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($mysqli_result)) {
    // do stuff...
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to loop:

```
$res=mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    echo $row['nDeCand'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_row` only fetches a single row.

Try `mysql_fetch_array` instead, then loop the array.